# Xero-node get invoice as PDF

Tags: parse-platform, electron, xero-api

I am trying to create an invoice in xero and then get a pdf version uploaded onto mongoDB through my parse server.
I am authenicating xero in an express app in the main.js of my application.
When I save the invoice Pdf to parse it is rejected as 'schema mismatch, expecting file but getting object', what am I missing in my code to create the PDF version?

```
let oauth_verifier = req.query.oauth_verifier;
let accessToken = await xeroClient.oauth1Client.swapRequestTokenforAccessToken(lastRequestToken, oauth_verifier)
    .then(async() => {
        var invoice = xeroClient.invoices.create(data)
            .then(async(invoice) => {
                var inv = invoice["Invoices"][0];
                var invId = inv["InvoiceID"];
                await xeroClient.invoices.get({ InvoiceID: invId}, "application/pdf")
                    .then((invPdf) => {

                        Parse.initialize("--------------------");    
                        Parse.serverURL = 'http://--.---.---.--:--/parse';
                        var Invoices = Parse.Object.extend("Invoices");
                        var invoice = new Invoices;
                        invoice.set('invoicePdf', invPdf);
                        invoice.save(); 

                        event.returnValue = true;
                        win.close();
                    })
            })
```

Comment: First thing I'd do* is to see if the return is actually coming back as a PDF file, narrow down the problem - don't you need to specify somewhere that your string "application/pdf" is the "Accept" header, or is that implied in the function? (* - I'm not familiar with the language you're using here, never mind much of the rest of it).

Comment: If it's Node.js, the code in github suggests that the only header-args the function supports is "If-modified-since" - https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/blob/ce69368/src/AccountingAPIClient.ts#L62 - which would suggest that even if you specify "Accept: application/pdf", the `get` call will ignore it.

Comment: i have seen this suggested, but not sure exactly how to use it.


`var invoice =  xero.getInvoice(invoiceId, modifiedAfter, where, "application/pdf");  
var content = invoice.PdfContentRaw;
var filename = invoice.FileName;`

Comment: Can you please console.log(invPdf) and share what you have in this var?

Comment: Hi Davi, it gives an object:-
`{ Id: '30afd09c-2125-4c76-815e-dbf72be5fe7a',
  Status: 'OK',
  ProviderName: 'bibwine-mds',
  DateTimeUTC: '/Date(1562067286613)/',
  Invoices:
   [ { Type: 'ACCREC',
       InvoiceID: 'ad2892fd-df50-43c7-b026-c9a57295ebea',
       InvoiceNumber: 'INV-0137',
       Reference: '',
       Status: 'DRAFT',
       LineAmountTypes: 'Exclusive',
       LineItems: [Array],
       SubTotal: 400,
       TotalTax: 0,
       Total: 400,
       UpdatedDateUTC: '/Date(1562067285793+0000)/',
       CurrencyCode: 'GBP' } ] }`

Comment: OK, so that has ignored the request to send the invoice as a PDF. If you try your original request but replace your string "application/pdf" with "Accept: application/pdf", does that make any difference?

Comment: Same result unfortunately
`Error: schema mismatch for Invoices.invoicePdf; expected File but got Object`

Comment: If you have a look at that link to GitHub for the Xero Node API, there is the "savePDF" function as well - have you tried that? https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/blob/36ab8a513263426a173633691f5308237f473b99/src/AccountingAPIClient.ts#L469

Comment: Well spotted. Below code is working now. Cheers Droopsnoot

`await xeroClient.invoices.savePDF({ InvoiceID: invId, savePath: path.join(__dirname, invNumber + '.pdf',)})`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then, in case it makes it more noticeable for anyone else searching.

Answer (score 1):

In the GitHub source for the Node.JS, there is a separate function called `savePDF` which seems to do the trick, as you noted in the comments above. https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/blob/36ab8a513263426a173633691f5308237f473b99/src/AccountingAPIClient.ts#L469